# How to read chars from a file and store them into a string in C?

Tags: c

Im trying to read a line of chars from a file, place each char into a string and then use the string in various ways. I've only posted printing cause that was the first of a few things I want try out but that doesnt work. My code doesnt print any values for the string. I apologize if format is bad but Im writing on my phone as I have no internet at home.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    File*fp = fopen(argv[1]);
    char curr;
    char string[7];
    int i = 0;

     while(curr != EOF){

             string[i] = curr;
             printf("%c\n", curr);
             curr = fgetc(fp);
              i++;
      }

      string[7] = '\0';
      printf("%s\n",string);
      return 0;
}
```

I would usually pass test.txt into it which simply has the letters a-f in it. How can I fix this code?

Edit: Placed '\0' at end of line with string[7]. Was a typo

Comment: what are u trying to do with ` string[7];`? in order to terminate the string you need to add \0 and also make the array longer. char string[8]; ... string[7]='\0';

Comment: 1) `File*fp` --> `FILE *fp` 2) `char curr;` --> `int curr;` 3) `while(curr != EOF){` --> `while((curr = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && i < 6){` and delete it inside while-loop. 4) `string[7] = '\0';` --> `string[i] = '\0';`

Comment: The amount of letters are correct. Curr prints fine but string doesn't. I am using this code as a test for a larger code where I need to read chars from a stream and place them into a string.

Comment: `while(curr != EOF){  string[i] = curr;` :  You are using uninitialized variables for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to read a line of chars from a file, place each char into a string and then use the string in various ways.

There are various ways to do this, for example `fgets` is a convenient way to get line from `fp`.

```
#define MAXLINE 1000
char string[MAXLINE];
if(fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp) != NULL)
{
    buffer[strcspn(string, "\n")] = 0; // remove \n from fgets
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

Comment: Im using this to make a larger piece of code where reading the whole line wont work. What I absolutely need to do is read char by char from a stream and place eaxh char in a char array and have a string at the end that I can call string functions on.

Comment: Reading char-by-char and then put the result in a string seems rather counter intuitive. Not sure why you have to do it while you can just put the input directly to a string.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems to point out in the comments below.

```
File*fp = fopen(argv[1]); // typo as FILE, and Need open mode
char curr;// Need int for curr != EOF
char string[7];
int i = 0;

 while(curr != EOF){// using uninitialized variables

         string[i] = curr;// using uninitialized variables
         printf("%c\n", curr);
         curr = fgetc(fp);
          i++;//Restriction required E.g i++ < 6
  }

  string[7] = '\0';//Outside array boundary
  printf("%s\n",string);
```

---

fix like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 7

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage:%s filename\n", *argv);
        return -1;
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!fp){
        perror("fopen");
        return -2;
    }
    int curr;
    char string[SIZE];
    int i = 0;

    while(i < SIZE -1 && (curr = fgetc(fp))!= EOF){//-1 for NUL
         string[i++] = curr;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    string[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",string);
    return 0;
}
```